# How much processing power is enough for mdadm?

Tags: raid, mdadm, software-raid, raid1

I am currently using RAID 1 (4TB X 2)as a motherboard feature with my Linux machine, lately I came across issues of not detecting properly when I moved to Ubuntu 16.04 64bit. So I was thinking if switching to software RAID instead of hardware raid using mdadm.

The question here, how much processing power will I need in order for this to work? and my machine runs smoothly? Considering that my machine is from 2011.

I got  Intel Core i5 2.8GHZ. RAM: 4 GB DDR3

Note: I have about 1TB of data. Will this be a heavy on the machine when syncing?

Please advice me.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a workstation- or server-class motherboard (and even then...), it’s very likely that your “hardware” RAID is implemented in software. You won’t see any performance difference between that and `md`.

Anyway, a 2011 system is easily capable of using software RAID; for RAID1 there is hardly any processing involved, it’s just more I/O. When you’re syncing, you can specify how much disk bandwidth `md` is allowed to use if you find it’s affecting your system’s performance, but the defaults will be fine in the vast majority of cases (they err on the side of caution).